# How to make Oracle case insensitive

Tags: oracle, plsql, case-insensitive

Is there be a setting in Oracle 10g to consider data as case insensitive?  I saw a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031844/oracle-db-how-can-i-write-query-ignoring-case/1031995#1031995).  However, that is done on a session.  What I am looking for is a setting either on a schema or on a table to consider its data as case insensitive.  If it is on a session then I will have to make the change on all the stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to make a schema or table 'case insensitive'.

- You can do that **on the session** using the NLS_ parameters or do the same in the db init file where the whole instance is affected.
  However those searches are only case-insensitive **for strict equality searches.**
- If you **need to use LIKE** you then need to consider using REGEXP_LIKE. 
  In the case of REGEXP_LIKE you don't need an NLS_SORT setting because there is an option for REGEXP_LIKE to have it consider things case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Case sensitivity is fundamental to computing, for the simple reason that the ASCII value of 'yun' != the ASCII value of 'YUN'.  So, when you say ...

> consider data as case insensitive

... do you mean just for the purposes of search or for storage as well?

The problem with enforcing case on every search is this:

```
SQL> create table t23 (id number, name varchar2(20))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create unique index  t23_uk on t23(name)
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> insert into t23 values (1, 'SAM-I-AM')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t23 values (2, 'sam-i-am')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> select id, name, ascii(name) from t23
  2  /

        ID NAME                 ASCII(NAME)
---------- -------------------- -----------
         1 SAM-I-AM                      83
         2 sam-i-am                     115

SQL>
```

If case insensitive searches are enforced at the schema or table level how can we ever distinguish 'sam-I-am' from 'SAM-I-AM'?

It is - sort of - possible to enforce case-insensitivity for data storage, albeit at the individual column level:

```
SQL> delete from t23
  2  /

2 rows deleted.

SQL> drop index t23_uk
  2  /

Index dropped.

SQL> create unique index  t23_uk on t23(upper(name))
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> insert into t23 values (1, 'SAM-I-AM')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t23 values (2, 'sam-i-am')
  2  /
insert into t23 values (2, 'sam-i-am')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.T23_UK) violated


SQL>
```