# Ignore Case In Query

Tags: oracle, select, case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle DB: How can I write query ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031844/oracle-db-how-can-i-write-query-ignoring-case)

I have an sql query it and the where condition contains english and arabic characters so i can not use toupper or tolower because the arabic characters will be shown as question marks.

DBMS is oracle

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401799/896341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean `lower()` and `upper()` right?

Oracle supports many [different languages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58242/ch4.htm), which means you need to use a `nls` function. In this case [`nls_lower`](http://psoug.org/reference/string_func.html).

```
select nls_lower('my string', 'NLS_SORT = ARABIC') from dual
```

This may cause problems with latin characters - it's worth checking your output, so you might want to do something similar to the below to mitigate:

```
select case when instr(lower('my_string'),'?') > 0
                 then nls_lower('my string', 'NLS_SORT = ARABIC')
            else lower('my_string')
  from dual
```