# Case insensitive oracle query

Tags: oracle, jsp, case-insensitive

I am working with database where i need to retrieve distinct values. Example [English enGLish english ....] all this should be displayed as English only. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is i can not use alter function. Is there any other way to achieve this? And values are inserted by someone else so i do not know what kind of case they have used. It should be done dynamically.

Comment: @yasmeen You might want to read other answers as well, not only the accepted one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031844/oracle-db-how-can-i-write-query-ignoring-case#1031865

Comment: the other answers work too... "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (TABLE.NAME,'IgNoReCaSe','i');" and "Select * from table where upper(table.name) like upper('IgNoreCaSe')"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need function **[`initcap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm)**:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/QHEQJ92547)</sup>**

```
select distinct initcap(column_name) from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working.